# xaml wpf - Gradient Brush resource doesn't work correctly

Tags: wpf, xaml, colors

I'm already desperate to find the answer why this happens... here's my code:

ResourceDictionary

```
<Color x:Key="ControlStrokeColorDefault">#0F000000</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlStrokeColorSecondary">#29000000</Color>
    
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ControlElevationBorderBrush" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,3">
        <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
            <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" ScaleY="-1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.33" Color="{DynamicResource ControlStrokeColorSecondary}" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="{DynamicResource ControlStrokeColorDefault}" />
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Panel

```
<Grid Background="#29000000">
        <WrapPanel Background="#F7F7F7"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Border Margin="20" Width="100" Height="60" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ControlElevationBorderBrush}">
                <TextBlock>Ok</TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <Border Margin="20" Width="100" Height="100" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ControlElevationBorderBrush}">
                <TextBlock>???</TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

As a [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFKsQ.png), I get that the gradient is calculated only on the first element... is this a wpf bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

this is because of ScaleY="-1" in ScaleTransform
Scale creates different sizes at different heights

Comment: I know it's because of ScaleY="-1" My question is why it does not calculate for other heights